# Make aria-selected true on selected tab on click in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a reusable navigation "tabs" component where I would like the selected tab to be set to "true" for aria-selected on click, however aria-selected is remaining false for all three tabs on click. How do I set an individual tab to true if it is clicked?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  tabs = [
    { tabName: 'tab1' },
    { tabName: 'tab2' },
    { tabName: 'tab3' }
  ]
  selected: boolean;

  select(tab){
    this.selected = tab.tabName
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div role="tablist">
  <app-tabs 
  *ngFor="let tab of tabs" 
  (click)="select(tab)"
  [selected]="selected" 
  [tab]="tab">
  </app-tabs>
</div>
```

tabs.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.css']
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tab
  @Input() selected

}
```

tabs.component.html

```
<span 
role="tab" 
(click)="handleSelected($event)" 
aria-selected="tab.tabName === selected">
  {{tab.tabName}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `[attr.aria-selected]="tab.tabName === selected"` instead of `aria-selected="tab.tabName === selected"`. The former is binding to a property of the component class, the later is just passing the literal value

Comment: Getting this error: Can't bind to 'aria-selected' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.

Comment: use attr.aria-selected instead, this skips the check

Comment: Excuse me, forgot to add `attr` at the beginning of the binding. Updated the question, it should be working now

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
 //html
<button [attr.aria-selected]="variable1"></button>

//ts
class AppComponent {

this.variable1=true;

}
```